# How to change column visibility by Column ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to make a column visible if its checkbox is selected. I have this function:

```
function SaveTableSettings() {
    var notChecked = [], checked = [];
    var table = $('#data-table');
    $(":checkbox").each(function() {
        if(this.checked){
            checked.push(this.id);

        } else {
            notChecked.push(this.id);
        }
});
```

And I want to use the elements of the "checked" array and change corresponding column visibility with this function :

```
if (dataTableId == "data-table"&&toShow.length<1) {
    alert("in if");
    table.column(1).visible(false);
    table.column(2).visible(false);
    table.column(3).visible(false);
    table.column(4).visible(false);
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < toShow.length; i++) {

    }
}
```

where "toShow" is the same array with to "checked" I passed it as parameter. I want to make the column which is in the array visible .But I do not know what to do in the for loop. Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you provide some more code? Or a jsFiddle? That would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Buttons extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) for that purpose, and to be more precise you should use [the column visibility plug-in for Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html).

Here is the basic usage example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'colvis'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

You have to include the relevant JavaScript files, for example:

- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js

Alternatively, use [Download builder](http://datatables.net/download/index) and include DataTables with Buttons and Column visibility modules.

p.s In case that you use old datatables (1.9.x you should use the [ColVis extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/colvis/)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to debug your code without the markup / HTML, but to me it somehow seems like you are trying to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Instead of `id`'s (?) simply use an attribute to bind the checkbox to a certain column :

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-column="0" checked/>
```

And in your `SaveTableSettings()` or whatever :

```js
$("[data-column]").each(function() {
    table.column($(this).data('column')).visible($(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

a small demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/c0o48jmv/1/**

---

The above can easily be changed to target `id`'s instead of column indexes. Simply add `id`'s to your `<th>`'s

```
<th id="col0">columnHeader</th>
```

and refer to those `id`'s instead of the indexes

```
<input type="checkbox" data-column="#col0" checked/>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/d9q06cg0/**

Comment: Made a small change, for when you don't want to use the update button.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zt59rhn2/
using a class or id in selector might be needed.